# Can't for the life of me get rpy2 installed - gcc error

Tags: python, r, gcc, rpy2

I've gotten so many different install/build errors in trying to setup rpy2 on my Ubuntu 14.04 server in a virtual environment that I've lost track.  This is the last step I have in setting up my iPython server, but I've been stuck on the rpy2 install for several days now.  I've tried many different things, some of which I'm sure are conflicting with each other and making my life harder (such as the dual R version installs), but I'm giving up trying to do this without outside help.

Various things I've done:

- Installed python-dev and setuptools
- Installed and updated pip
- Installed and updated gcc
- Build and install the newest version of R from source
- Build and install the development version of R (r-devel) from source using [Dirk Eddelbuetel's Docker file](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/rocker/r-devel/dockerfile/)
- [sudo] pip install rpy2 with stable R *and* development R
- build rpy2 from source with stable R *and* development R (with [--ignore-check-rversion](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/overview.html) option set)
- easy_install rpy2
- pip install and source install with and without R_HOME set to stable R (current default R is the unstable development verison)

If anyone has any idea what I can do to get this working, besides starting from scratch in a clean environment, then please let me know - it will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!!

The current error that I'm getting is as follows:

```
(.venv)zacp@contentvalue:~/rpy2-2.6.0$ python setup.py build_ext --ignore-check-rversion install
R Under development (unstable) (2015-06-16 r68524) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"
setup.py:196: UserWarning: R did not seem to have the minimum required version number
  warnings.warn("R did not seem to have the minimum required version number")
/usr/local/lib/R/bin/R CMD config --ldflags
R was not built as a library
/usr/local/lib/R/bin/R CMD config --cppflags
R was not built as a library
setup.py:211: UserWarning: No include specified
  warnings.warn('No include specified')
setup.py:222: UserWarning: No libraries as -l arguments to the compiler.
  warnings.warn('No libraries as -l arguments to the compiler.')

    Compilation parameters for rpy2's C components:
        include_dirs    = []
        library_dirs    = []
        libraries       = []
        extra_link_args = []

running build_ext
R Under development (unstable) (2015-06-16 r68524) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"
setup.py:77: UserWarning: R did not seem to have the minimum required version number
  warnings.warn("R did not seem to have the minimum required version number")
building 'rpy2.rinterface._rinterface' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -DR_INTERFACE_PTRS=1 -DHAVE_POSIX_SIGJMP=1 -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND=1 -DCSTACK_DEFNS=1 -DHAS_READLINE=1 -I./rpy/rinterface -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/include/python2.7 -c ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o
In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:55:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1182:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/signal.h:28:0,
                 from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:51:
/usr/include/features.h:230:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 # define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
 ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:58:0:
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:8:15: fatal error: R.h: No such file or directory
 #include <R.h>
               ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: What's your R version?

Comment: R Under development (unstable) (2015-06-16 r68524) -- "Unsuffered Consequences"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Comment: I also have 3.0.2 "Frisbee Sailing" installed, but the default is set as the development version

Answer (score 0):

I guess the version of R that I installed with apt-get was out-of-date.  R 3.0 is "probably OK" according to the [documentation](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.5/html/overview.html), and I guess I misinterpreted the warnings.
Whoops!

Comment: So can you clarify how you resolved it? Or at least which versions you were using, and what you learned about which versions are required?

Answer (score 0):

According to [pip - Unable to Install rpy2 on Ubuntu 14.04, missing R_ext/Rallocators.h: - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/681142/6130), you need something more recent than R version 3.0.2, and version 3.2 was recent enough.  That seems to be true e.g. for rpy2 version 2.8.5.